# How to initialize parameterised constructor as default constructor in c++?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

How to initialize parameterised constructor as default constructor in c++?
This question was asked in my exam. We were given a parametrized constructor & it worked as default constructor too.

Answer (score 5):

A default constructor, per standard (12.1/4), is:

> A
>   default
>   constructor for a class
>   X
>   is a constructor of class
>   X
>   that can be called without an argument

So you just need to give the arguments default values:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int a = 6)
    {

    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A
{
    A(int a = 0)
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
};
```

Just predefine the parameters with default values.

Answer (score 0):

When a constructor can be invoked with no arguments, it is called a default constructor.

However, a constructor that takes arguments can be turned into a default constructor when its arguments are given default values.

For example:

```
class String {
public:
    String(const char∗ p = ""); // default constructor : empty string
    // ...
}
```